# Idiom for a shy girl

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What do you tell a girl who shies away from expressing her feelings and avoids saying what you expect her to?

Comment: This question is fine here, and I hope you get some good answers. However, I think you might also be interested in ELU's sister site, [ell.se]. You can read more about the two sites [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722), and decide where you might want to ask your next question.

Comment: What do you mean by “avoids saying what you expect her [to]”? What do you in general ‘expect’ a girl to say that this one doesn’t?

Comment: I think you mean *what do you **call*** ... To *tell* a girl something is to give her something as information.

Comment: It’s quite possible that you’re completely misreading this **[coy](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/coy)** young woman’s feelings for and message to you.

Comment: You "tell" the girl to : talk, communicate, be confident,  become an extrovert, outgoing, unreserved, unshy, forward, unrestrained person.

Comment: @StoneyB is hopefully correct that you meant to say “call” instead of “tell” (otherwise your question would be better suited for a ‘love advice’ forum, imo), but if you did mean “tell,”  I’d advise you to ‘tell’ her (again and again) exactly how **you** feel towards her and that you certainly don’t ‘expect’ her to feel the same way towards you, but if she does, it would make you very happy.

Comment: by "avoids saying what you expect her to", might you mean, "avoids responding to questions"?

Comment: There is just no reason to believe you're not in command of the language and that you meant call instead of tell etc. Therefore, the answer is you just leave her be; people are not accountable to others about their feelings and need not be lectured about self-expression when this is in fact about scrutinizing someone else's intimacy for one's own interest. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

**[Quiet as a mouse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as-quiet-as-a-mouse-or-lamb?q=%20quiet%20as%20a%20mouse)**

> (of a person or animal) extremely quiet or docile.

**[Wallflower](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wallflower?q=%20Wallflower)**

> a shy or excluded person at a dance or party, especially a girl without a partner.

**[Shrinking violet/Modest violet](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/descp-people/descr-pp7-plum-sit.html)**

> A person referred to as a shrinking violet is a timid or shy person.

**Reserved**

> slow to reveal emotion or opinions.

**Uncommunicative**

> unwilling to talk or impart information.

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

In a more general sense, you could use 'introvert', though this is not a specific term. Anyone who keeps things to himself and doesn't disclose his thoughts to many people is an 'introvert'.

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Comment: Feels like these should each be separate answers, but I'd go with "wallflower"/

Comment: +1... (as) quiet as a mouse (or lamb)

Comment: Shrinking violet is excellent.

Comment: I disagree about the introvert part, shyness is not always related to introversion

Answer (score 14):

The adjective [***demure***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demure) also describes such a woman:

> (Of a woman or her behavior) reserved, modest, and shy:
> *a *demure* little wife who sits at home minding the house*
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting on my question. Yet, some misunderstood me and tried to correct me by suggesting "call" fot "tell"! I did mean "tell". I'm looking for an imperative expression not an adjective!

Answer (score 11):

You could use

**[reticent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reticent)**

> Not revealing one’s thoughts or feelings readily:
>
> *she was extremely reticent about her personal affairs*

Synonyms include:

[Diffident](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diffident)

> Modest or shy because of a lack of self-confidence:

[Guarded](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/guarded)

> (of a person or a remark they make) careful; not showing feelings or giving much information

[Taciturn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taciturn#taciturn__2)

> (Of a person) reserved or uncommunicative in speech; saying little:

(Oxford)

Comment: Importantly, of these options, only _guarded_ is neutral—the rest all have definite, negative connotations to them.

Comment: I concur with @Janus

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet personally, I would not consider *taciturn* to have a negative connotation. On the contrary, to me, *guarded* suggests that a person actively wishes to avoid conversation about some particular subject, which can be seen as obtuse or incriminating, whereas *taciturn* simply connotes that they are not an enthusiastic communicator.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, guarded suggests that you actively wish to avoid speaking about a subject—but it doesn’t necessarily imply that’s a bad thing. Being guarded about something is often wise. _Taciturn_ has overtones of ‘sullen’ and ‘sulky’ to me; a quick survey of a few dictionaries doesn’t yield any definitions that include this aspect, though, so perhaps that’s just me.

Comment: I would read a negative connotation into "guarded", but not any of the others.

Answer (score 4):

Wallflower

> informal
>   a person who has no one to dance with or who feels shy, awkward, or excluded  at a party.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe also [*Buttoned-down*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/button-down)

> conservatively traditional or conventional; especially :  adhering to conventional norms in dress and behavior